# É uma boa escolha começar um projeto com Diagrama casos de uso, depois diagrama de classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, classes, diagrama, casos-de-uso

Tenho uma ideia de software, mas não sei se devo partir diretamente para o diagrama de classes e depois a codificação ou se antes de tudo devo usar um diagrama de casos de uso. Trabalharei nesse software sozinho. É um sonho de longo prazo que farei nas minha horas vagas, sem pressa!
Trabalho com .NET c# MVC.

Comment: Olá!!!
Eu trabalho com programação web em php, sempre faço um diagrama de casos de uso , pois me dá uma base melhor do que devo fazer e quais pontos são mais importantes para o sistema funcionar. Mas quando se trata de um projeto individual esse método se torna um tanto pessoal, enfim, espero ter ajudado amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Essa resposta baseia se integralmente em minha **opinião**.

*Diagramas* é um modo de gestão/especificação/documentação muito *old school*.

Busque documentar suas requisições via *[User Stories](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hist%C3%B3ria_de_usu%C3%A1rio)*. São mais simples de criar, e depois de interpretar para desenvolver.

Exemplo de uma *User Story*:

> > *COMO* um visitante do site
> >
> > *QUANDO* estou na página inicial do site
> >
> > *E* clico no link "Registrar-se"
> >
> > *ENTÃO* um formulário de registro deve abrir.
>
> Dados do formulário: nome completo, email e senha.

Cada *user story* possui um tipo. Ex:

- **Feature**: Nova funcionalidade ou mudança;
- **Bug**: Correção de algo implementado;
- **Epic**: Exige que outras *user stories* sejam criadas para atender esse desejo.
- **Tech**: Alterações propostas pelos desenvolvedores que não afetam o negócio. Como atualizar Nuget Packages, criar tracking para Application Insights, etc.

Possuem fases:

- **Icebox**: Apenas foram criadas afim de serem analisadas no futuro - que pode ser em breve, em anos, ou mesmo nunca. A ideia é jamais deixar de escrever uma ideia e perder alguma coisa..
- **Backlog**: A história será sim implementada e está na fila para ser desenvolvida
- **Finished**: A história já foi desenvolvida ou foi abortada.

**Importante**: Essas fases não necessariamente refletem as fases de um desenvolvimento de software. Comumente sim, refletem, mas não é o caso do meu exemplo. É comum ver fases como "Iniciado", "Finalizado", "Em testes", "Aprovado para produção", etc.

E possuem "Pontos de Complexidade" ou "Pontos de Esforço". Esse deve seguir a [Sequencia de Fibonacci](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequ%C3%AAncia_de_Fibonacci):

- **1 pt**: Apenas correção de digitação, alteração de textos. Não envolve mudança de códigos.
- **2 pts**: Pequenas alterações de código ou tela. Nada que altere regras de negócio, criticidade ou testes específicos.
- **3 pts**: Esforço regular como criar uma nova feature simples, telas, etc. É o mais comum.
- **5 pts**: Esforço grande, irá tocar em vários pontos do sistema, alterar grandes regras de negócio, afetar testes ou integração com outros sistemas.
- **8 pts**: Epico. Essa história deve ser quebradas em demais histórias mais simples.

Pode-se ir além. Existem estratégias que vão além do 21 pts. Eu não recomendo, começa ficar vago e difícil de entender o que é 5pts e o que é 8pts. Mas vai da sua estratégia e de como seu time se sente confortável.

Esses pontos não tem nenhuma relação com "horas de desenvolvimento" - o que para mim também é "old school", uma forma obsoleta de gerir demanda de projeto. Pense assim: Qual a complexidade de se varrer um chão? É bem baixa, varrer é simples. E o que muda de varrer um tapete de banheiro para um estacionamento? A complexidade é a mesma.

Existem vários sistemas para te auxiliar a gerir essas histórias.

- [Visual Studio Team Services](http://www.visualstudio.com): gratuito até 5 desenvolvedores, fornece também repositório Git e plataforma de Build & Release.
- [Trello](http://trello.com): Sistema simples de [Kanban](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban), gratuito.
- [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com): Pago, mas excelente sistema de gestão de *User Stories*.

**PS**: Acredito que sua pergunta será fechada por se tratar de opinião.

Comment: @Ivan, a resposta não te atendeu?